# input() обрабатывается не с первого раза

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, input

Пишу игру где нужно отгадать недостающие буквы в слове. Чтобы можно было выбирать конкретную букву я задействовал модуль `keyboard` и написал функцию, которая возвращает координату этой буквы, после чего пользователь должен ввести свой вариант ответа через `input()`. Однако `input()` обрабатывается не с первого раза, т.е. цикл прокручивается один раз, прежде чем представится возможность ввести букву. Из-за этого сразу же срабатывает if

```
     X = keyboard_d(enc_word) #фунция для выбора буквы
     os.system('CLS')

        while attempt != -1:
            print(enc_word)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            tr = input() #цикл прокручивается 1 раз прежде чем сработает inp
            if tr != word[X]: #word[x] - все недостающие буквы
                print("кол-во попыток: " + str(attempt))
                attempt -= 1
                time.sleep(2)
                os.system('CLS')
            else:
                ...
```

ссыылка .txt драйв, ибо не знаю как ужать код здесь: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nvULjBR2pXlxXgogRKl6QekXxwgM7DS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: На все ошибки кода поставил простенькие заглушки и описанной вами ошибки не наблюдается. Постарайтесь предоставить код в котором возможно воспроизвести данную ошибку.

Comment: Не знаю как ужать этот код до минимума здесь https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nvULjBR2pXlxXgogRKl6QekXxwgM7DS/view?usp=sharing